# Indexeddb : How to limit number of objects returned?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm using a cursor with a lower bound range query. I can't find a way to limit the number of objects returned, similar to a "LIMIT n" clause in a databse.

```
var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound('');
```

Does it not exist ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you're iterating through the results, you can stop at any time. Something like this should work:

```
var results = [];
var limit = 20;
var i = 0;

objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if (cursor && i < limit) {
    results.push(cursor.value);
    i += 1;
    cursor.continue();
  }
  else {
    // Do something with results, which has at most 20 entries
    console.log(results);
  }
};
```

Also, in the special case where you are selecting based on a key that is made up of sequential numbers, you could use a keyRange to explicitly return only a certain range. But that's generally not the case.

Comment: exactly, it's not my case. I implemented what you describe above but in my case the object store is quite large so it's really dumb to retrieve all the data from it... hence my question...

Comment: The code I posted isn't retrieving all the data, just the first 20 objects.

Comment: Yes you're right but is the cursor streaming the data out of the DB ? It may be preloading everything before handling it back to the JS engine. For example, the MySQL driver for Java does that.

Comment: Not that I've studied the source code of Chrome and Firefox to validate this, but it is supposed to be streaming the data out as you request it. I would be quite surprised if that wasn't the case.

Comment: Chrome uses heuristics to preload up to 100 objects.

Answer (score 2):

An important fix its replace:

```
if (cursor && i < limit) {
```

for

```
if (cursor && results.length < limit) {
```

Remember that its an async call, and it could be adding elements on "results" at the same time and "i" would not have the proper value.

Answer (score 0):

You can even search by range in indexedDB with `IDBKeyRange.bound` function

```
IDBKeyRange.bound(keyValueFrom, keyValueTo, false, true);
```

You can set the start value, end value and if you should include the start and end value in the returned items. In my case i want the first value of the range, however i want to exclude the last value.

For details of IDBKeyRange please visit the [W3C IndexedDB page](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#range-concept)

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I asked : I want bound(0,infinity) but return only the first N

Comment: why do you want to list through all items if you don't need em?
you can list first N items with IDBKeyRange.bound(0, N, false, true);

Comment: I have no way of setting the upper bound to only return 5, the value being queried isn't a sequence